# Android how to get "name" from clicked item

Tags: android

I need to get the item name from my listView clicked item.

The list is populated by items.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="menu_dx_items">
        <item name="0">A</item>
        <item name="7">B</item>
        <item name="2">C</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

I succesfully got the strings ("A","B" or "C") by clicking items in this way:

```
final ListView menuDx = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.menu_dx);
menuDx.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int pos,long id){
                    String item_text = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), item_text , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  }
            });
```

Now I'm trying to get the "name" parameter of the clicked item, any suggestions?

Comment: it is not possibile directly. What you are trying ti achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible, as the name is just the Resource ID that can be used to reference that object. (Seen here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#StringArray)

One workaround may be to have a separate string array that "maps" to this array, so when you know what index is click (say "A" is clicked), you can then check the "map" array for the value that should be associated with a.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="menu_dx_items">
        <item>A</item>
        <item>B</item>
        <item>C</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="menu_dx_item_map">
        <item>0</item>
        <item>7</item>
        <item>2</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

and

```
final ListView menuDx = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.menu_dx);
menuDx.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int     pos,long id){
                String item_text = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);
                // Now, get the value from the map array
                String item_val = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menu_dx_item_map)[pos];
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), item_text + " = " + item_val, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              }
        });
```